# What does a quantum mutual information larger than its classical upper bound represent?

Tags: information-theory, entropy, mutual-information, quantum-discord

Let $\rho$ be a bipartite state. Its [quantum mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mutual_information) is defined as
$$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}I(\rho) = S(\tr_B(\rho)) + S(\tr_A(\rho)) - S(\rho),$$
where $S(\sigma)$ is the von Neumann entropy of $\sigma$.
If $\rho$ is pure, then it's easy to see that $I(\rho)=2S(\tr_A(\rho))$.
If $\rho$ is also maximally entangled, then $I(\rho) = 2\log d$, with $d$ the dimension of the underlying space. This can also be written as $I(\rho)=2$, taking base-$d$ logarithms.

Now, let $\mu^A,\mu^B$ be some measurements for the first and second party. These will correspond to a joint probability distribution $p(a,b;\rho)\equiv \langle\mu^A_a\otimes\mu^B_b,\rho\rangle$. Let $p,p^A,p^B$ denote the corresponding probability distribution, and its two marginals, respectively. If $X,Y$ denote the random variables describing the corresponding outcomes, we can define a *classical* mutual information as
$$I_{\mu}(\rho) \equiv I(X:Y)\equiv
H(p^A) + H(p^B) - H(p),$$
with $H(p)$ the (classical) Shannon entropy of the probability distribution $p$.
Note that the maximum value of the classical mutual information, obtained for fully correlated variables, is $\log d$ (without the factor of $2$).

When $I(\rho)=2\log d$, and thus $\rho$ is maximally entangled, the parties can observe correlations in infinitely many (projective) measurement bases: for any choice of measurement basis for $A$, there is a choice of measurement basis for $B$ which gives fully correlated outcomes.
On the other hand, $I(\rho)=\log d$ can be obtained with the fully correlated mixed state: $\rho=\frac{1}{d}\sum_i |ii\rangle\!\langle ii|$, but said correlation can only be observed with a fixed choice of basis: unless the parties measure both in the computational basis, their outcomes won't be fully correlated.

Is the above intuition of any value in this context? In other words, can one think of the quantum mutual information being larger than its classical upper bound as being linked to the possibility of observing correlations in multiple measurement bases? Or is it just a red herring?

Comment: Shouldn't $I(\rho)=\log d$ instead of $1$ for the fully correlated mixed state?

Comment: @AdamZalcman indeed, fixed, thanks

Comment: I do think the intuition you describe is valuable in this context. My hunch is that the answer is some generalization of superdense coding where a shared quantum state allows one to send two bits of information instead of one. The excess bit is explained by entanglement and perhaps this is what's going to happen here, too. This is BTW a very interesting question that clarifies what it means that quantum correlations are stronger than classical ones.

Comment: @AdamZalcman thanks. What I'm not sure about is how this works more generally for $1<I<2$. We know $I=2$ implies maximal entanglement, which is easy to characterise, But when $I<2$ things are trickier. In particular, I'm not sure when this freedom in measurement bases which give full correlations is or isn't there. Are there such examples for $I<2$? Can there be such examples for $I\le 1$? The discord is probably relevant to this discussion, but I don't enough about it to tell

Comment: This paper connects quantum correlations with mutual information, and may be relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0410091.pdf

Comment: When you refer to a state that "shows correlations in multiple measurement bases", would it be right to assume that you are referring to a state that might violate some Bell's inequality? That is, a bipartite state that can produce a probability distribution of the form p(a, b|x, y) which is not obtainable classically?

In that case, I think the direction *might* be false, as there exist entangled states with positive conditional entropy (and thus they have mutual information less than log d). These states *may* show non-classical correlations, that is, violate some Bell's inequality.

Comment: late reply, but no, that's not what I mean. I'm talking about correlations between observations on the different parties, observable in different measurement choices. This is the same context in which you study Bell nonlocality, yes, but I'm focusing on whether the states violate some inequality. There might be strong relations, but I don't find it immediately obvious. The paper is certainly relevant though, thanks.